# why is the zero changing in c++

Tags: c++

so i'm new to c++. i have to make a program where you enter a number and it displays the largest possible number and the smallest one, with the same digits as the entered number. But when the entered number has 0 it changes to 4310160

sorry for my english;{

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m[10], i, l, x, c, ok, r;

    cout << "x= ";
    cin >> x;

    l = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        c = x % 10;
        m[l] = c;
        l++;
        x = x / 10;
    }

    do {
        ok = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
            if (m[i] < m[i + 1]) {
                r = m[i];
                m[i] = m[i + 1];
                m[i + 1] = r;
                ok = 0;
            }
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            cout << m[i] << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } while (ok != 1);
    cout << "largest= ";
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cout << m[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    do {
        ok = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
            if (m[i] > m[i + 1]) {
                r = m[i];
                m[i] = m[i + 1];
                m[i + 1] = r;
                ok = 0;
            }
    } while (ok != 1);
    if (m[0] == 0) {
        r = m[0];
        m[0] = m[1];
        m[1] = r;
    }
    cout << "smallest= ";
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cout << m[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run your program in a debugger? Step line by line through the code and see what happens.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I tried it on ideone https://ideone.com/aYI82B and keept input 0 it output is x= 
largest= 
smallest=               Nothing printed on output

Comment: you are going past the end of the entered digits. Look more carefully at anything involving m[i+1]

Comment: Get that number as string, either by receiving from `std::cin` or converting later. Then sort characters. Ascedning order - smallest number, descending - biggest.

Comment: If you enter 0, the first loop never sets any values to your variables.  You then use uninitialized memory for your comparisons in the bottom with `m[0] == 0`.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you could simplify your code. If you've got the largest number, just print out the digits in reverse to show the smallest.

Answer (score 3):

if `x == 0`, you do

```
if (m[0] == 0) {
    r = m[0];
    m[0] = m[1];
    m[1] = r;
}
```

With uninitialized `m`, leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `int m[10]` array in `main` is stored in the stack and its elements initialized to indeterminate values as explained in [array_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) and [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization).

So if `x == 0` , the program should print nothing as `l` will be `0` and it won't enter in any loop.

If you see `4310160` because you are debugging, it is because `m[10]` elements are initialized to indeterminate values (normally, the value at the stack in that moment.)

You may see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/) that local, non static data is stored in the stack.